# Is there anyway to get the current state of job within the steps in github actions?

Tags: node.js, github-actions, octokit-js

I have been working on the github actions and I need to send the message about the reason of failure on the external webhook. I tried to use the octokit rest js in the nodejs action, but Since the job isn't completed, I am unable to fetch the reason of failure of current job. Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Comment: Start by browsing through this [list](https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions#notifications-and-messages) of actions that offer this functionality

Comment: I am not sure that it's possible atm. I was trying to get the reason of step/job failure starting from directly in the next step/job and ending by calling [GitHub Actions API](https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/workflow-jobs/), result is the same - no chance to get failure reasons (only _status: failure_). If someone knows how to do it I would be love to "hear" the solution as well.